# Avoid rendering a seperate layout's CSS file in rails 4 (conflicting stylesheets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a 'welcome' controller. I want to use a separate layout for this controller called welcome.html.erb which I want to use ONLY welcome.css.scss - I got this working.

Now I have a 'pages' controller that uses the default application layout. However, this application layout, which uses application.css.scss, also renders my OTHER layout's css (welcome.css.scss). This results in all of my pages actions looking all screwed up because my styles for the other layout are being applied.

---

welcome.html.erb (layout) css declaration

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'welcome', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks' => true %>
```

My application.html.erb (layout) is still the default set up.

---

To summarize, when I load the pages controller I specify my pages layout, which in turn just uses the welcome.css.scss - all is good. I click on a link which brings me to the pages controller and BAM ... it loads all of my css files and the welcome.css.scss conflicts with the application.css.scss.

Some possible solutions:

- Just add an id to the welcome.html.erb body tag to wrap all of its styles into its own little selector and add it to the application.css.scss (seems hackish)
- Possibly change the little declarations at the top of the application.css.scss?

I have been researching and experimenting for a while and I have resorted to S.O.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably got a line up the top of `application.css.scss`, in the comments, like this:

```
*= require_tree .
```

That is requiring ALL the files in your stylesheets directory. You'll need to remove it, and include just the ones you want, one by one.

Comment: So this would be, in your opinion, the best way to go about it? I figured there would be a way to keep the 'require_tree .' but avoid rendering a specific stylesheet. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's how I do it. There may be a way to include "all but stylesheet xyz", but I'm not aware of it. Personally, I prefer to be explicit about what I'm including, and don't like the idea of saying "just include everything", or "include everything but..."

Answer (score 3):

**Layouts**

To further `joshia.paling`'s answer, perhaps you'd be better looking into [how `layouts` work](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) - they basically alow you to define custom HTML for different parts of your app.

In the sense of calling a `layout`, you'll need to set it in the controller (the default is `application`):

```
#app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
Class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    layout "welcome"
end
```

This will call the layout located at `#app/views/layouts/welcome.html.erb`, in which you can reference the `welcome` assets only:

```
#app/views/layouts/welcome.html.erb
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'welcome', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks' => true %>
```

--

**Manifest**

As alluded to by `joshua.paling`, you'll then have to ensure you've *excluded* the `welcome` assets from your various asset pipeline [`manifests`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
*= require x
*= require y
```

If you're going to do this, you'll need to add your `welcome` assets to your precompilation settings:

```
#config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w(welcome.css)
```

Comment: When do you need to add to the pre-compilation settings? It seems when you generate controllers with the rails command that it creates new css files for you, but they are not declared in the pre-compilation settings. Do you understand what I am getting at?

Comment: Sure - when Rails precompiles your assets, it will essentially take your [`manifest`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives) files & compile them into a single file (typically `application.js` / `application.css`). Using the precompile option tells Rails to treat that particular file separately (creating it alongside `application.**`